# demo how to Transcribe an audio file using the SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I recently tried to learn how to transcribe an audio file, but I am not very familiar with python.

I have read the example from the SpeechRecognition from the following website

https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/audio_transcribe.py

I try to use them using the following code:

However, it looks like I cannot import my file in my windows computer.

I wonder if I have a wav file in my computer with the path

"C:\Users\Chen\Downloads\english.wav"

and I tried to replace the **file** with "C:\Users\Chen\Downloads" in my python code.

But it shows me that

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Chen\english.wav'

Please help me to fix the problems.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
# obtain path to "english.wav" in the same folder as this script
from os import path
AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "english.wav")

# use the audio file as the audio source
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file

print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Comment: Try `AUDIO_FILE = "C:\Users\Chen\Downloads\english.wav"`. And also try to understand what `path.dirname` does. You essentially strip 'Downloads' with `path.dirname`, thats why it fails to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use function listen() if you need to recognize text

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)  # read the entire audio file
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Below code is for audio file in hindi
file = "hindi.wav"
with sr.AudioFile(file) as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio,  language='hi-IN')
    print("Text :  " + text)
```

Comment: Its worth adding a few words to explain what you are doing and what was the problem